# Сделать объект невидимым для нажатий

Tags: spritekit, objective-c, ios7

Как сделать чтобы объект типа SKLabelNode был невидим для нажатий? То есть чтобы как бы нажатие на него не учитывалось, а на объект за ним учитывалось.

Answer (score 1):

Перегрузите методы класса родителя:

```
– touchesBegan:withEvent:
– touchesMoved:withEvent:
– touchesEnded:withEvent:
– touchesCancelled:withEvent:
```

и не вызывайте super.